# I am trying to show data in summer note using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to show data in summer note from ajax request but unfortunately it's not showing on summer note please help me  how can i resolve that ? thank u.

[image]

**html view**

```
               <div class="form-outline">
                    <div class="form-outline mb-2">
                        <textarea  class="summernote" id="description" name="description" 
                      height="200px" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**ajax script**

```
       $(document).on('click','.editBtn',function(){
            var notificationId = $(this).data("id");
            $("#editModel").modal('show');
            var url = "{{URL('/notification/edit/')}}";
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: url + '/' + notificationId,
                  dataType:'JSON',
                success:function (response){
                        console.log(response);

                    $('#description').val(response.description);
                }
            });
       });
```

Comment: Can you try Like This .
$("textarea#description").val(response.description);
might work.not 100% sure.

Comment: sir this code is working   $('#description').summernote('code', response.description);

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: url + '/' + notificationId,
              dataType:'JSON',
            success:function (response){
                    console.log(response);

                $('#description').val(response.description);
            }
        });
```

**To Fix The Problem Above Please Follow The Answer Below**

```
 $('#description').val(response.description);
Remove the code Above From Your Project and Replace By This

    $('#description').summernote('code', response.description);
```

You dont have to use the `.val` at this time when you displaying or Fetching Result from Summernote But For others data to fetch for example like titile,meta_title and non-summernoted text or others data through the first code you mentioned or the code below

```
     $('#description').val(response.description);
```

finally this may help you a little thank you